# relative pronoun' which '

Tags: grammar

> There has been an enormous increase in the number of shops, stores and supermarkets which provide facilities for self-service.

I am not sure what "which" refers to. Does it refer to supermarkets or other?

Comment: The absence of an 'Oxford comma' after 'stores' adds support to the [ {A, B and C} which ...] here rather than the [ {A and B} – and C which ...] interpretation.

Comment: Then what does 'which '   without comma after ' stores ' and with comma after 'stores' refer to ?

Comment: 'shops, stores and supermarkets' = 'retail outlets'.

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? Can you link the source? Who wrote it?

Answer (score 0):

It is formally ambiguous.

There is no way to tell from the presentation of the sentence whether the relative clause applies just to "supermarkets" or to "shops, stores and supermarkets".

Only real-world considerations allow us to conclude which, and without context we cannot do that. If the context is an article about self-service, it is probably the latter. if the articles is about retail in general, it may be the former.

Having said all that, I find the most natural reading to be the inclusive one, but this cannot be relied on.

The presence of a comma would force the inclusive reading, but its absence leaves the question open.